# Putting Ubuntu Server on to a networked HDD

Tags: wireless, networking, server, hard-drive

Firstly, I know very little about servers and secondly the 1Tb HDD I have has network capabilities, but no software is installed on it, so when connected to the computer it is seen as a network connection, but not as a drive. Any advice on how to get started  would be great.

[image: The network screen shot]

Up until now, I have been using it as a USB drive which worked well, but when this is sorted, I would like it to be connected directly to our BT HomeHub accessible through the WiFi for all the family to use as a film and back up repository. I would then be able to set up individual accounts for each family member to use and may be, if possible, make it accessible from outside locations.

**The First question then is:**

  How can I install Ubuntu server on the 1Tb HDD attached directly to the computers network port but which doesn't show up in Nautilus?

- HDD Western Digital
- 1.0Tb LBA 1953525168
- Model: WD10EACS-00DB0
- DCM: DHRNHT2CF

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What drive is it?

Comment: Good question, I'll strip it down and find out...

Comment: Sorry I mean the NAS - what is the make and model of this mythical half networked, half usb'd beast?

Comment: Description and images added to the question :)

Comment: The descriptions you posted are all only related to the HDD that is located in the NAS. The HDD alone has no network capabilities. You have to give us some information about the case the HDD is attached to.

Comment: I have added pictures of the board the Hard Disk is plugged in to... I did say I didn't know much about it:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On second thought i might have misunderstood what you really want to achieve. To sum things up:

- You used the NAS directly connected with USB
- You want that NAS to be shown as network drive to all the computer in the LAN
- You want to install Ubuntu on the NAS?

The third question is the one that bugs me ;) Usually a NAS comes with some pre-installed proprietary software, my guess is that you can not install Ubuntu on the NAS.

Usually the NAS has some sort of configuration interface, look it up in the manual, or give some more detail about the NAS you have in use.

I thought you want to use that NAS as root filesystem for your ubuntu server, guess I am wrong, ill leave the previous answer below anyway:

---

Ill give you some hints. Yes, you can use your computer without a physical harddrive.

To make that work you have to use [PXE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preboot_Execution_Environment) in combination with a `DHCP` server, a `TFTP` server and a `NFS` server. I don't know if the NAS you are using has that capabilities. All in all this will be no trivial task, but it is of course possible.

PXE is used as the first step, your bios and the network card have to support that, check the bios settings for *network boot* or something similar.

The steps are the following:

1. PXE fetches a ip address from the DHCP server and the ip address of the availabe PXE boot server.
2. Once a PXE boot server is found, the data is transfered using TFTP, mainly the kernel image and the initrd.
3. Once the kernel has been loaded, the NFS server is used for providing the root filesystem.

There are some [tutorials](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DisklessUbuntuHowto) out there, i suggest you read through them and take your time to set the things up in a testing environment. You could use [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) for example, the guest NICs support PXE.

Good luck!

Comment: When I first got the HDD, it worked as a network drive, but when I found that it worked through USB, I formatted it and it seems as though I wiped any OS that was on there.

Comment: It seems that way, you have to re-install the software then. Iam sure there is some tool or something available for that, take a look at the website of the manufacturer of your NAS.